# How to solve "LibXml/xmlreader.h Not found" error in Twitter integration in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to integrate Twitter in my application. I integrated related files and added libxml2
     library.  I included the path for it in "Header Search paths" field. When i try to build my application, I am getting errors showing that `LibXml/xmlreader.h: No Such file or Directory`.

Can anyone please help me in this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Accept some answer before asking other questions, by simply checking the tickmark before the answers. 

Comment: Thanks Lakshmi for asking this question, the answer really helped me. The Credit goes to you aswell.

Answer (score 54):

Go to the project > Targets > Build Settings

Search Header Search Paths

Add

```
$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2
```

Make sure

Build Settings -> Always Search User Paths -> YES

Comment: I was able to fix the error by adding `"$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2"` (including double quotes).