# xcode Error to export archive to Application with OSStatus error 67028

Tags: xcode, macos

I am building [pomodoro](https://github.com/ugol/pomodoro) project in xcode 5.0.2.

I follow the document describe for Xcode 4.3+

```
1) Remove Code signing identity if present (should not, but sometimes I push it back)

Xcode 4.3+ (tips from @sashalaundy):    
1) Product > Edit Scheme
2) At top set Scheme to "Pomodoro" and Destination to "My Mac __-bit"
3) On left select Archive
4) Type in Archive Name "Pomodoro"
5) Hit OK
6) Product > Archive - Xcode builds and then opens Organizer with archive selected
7) Hit Distribute
8) Choose Export as "Application"
```

I fixed a compile error follow [How to solve "LibXml/xmlreader.h Not found" error in Twitter integration in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592193/how-to-solve-libxml-xmlreader-h-not-found-error-in-twitter-integration-in-ipho)

At last I goto step 8, the error occurs The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -67028.)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

From the [Code Signing Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/CodeSigningRef/Reference/reference.html) error -67028 is:

> errSecCSBadBundleFormat: The bundle format is unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable.

I have not found a solution to exporting the application from Xcode; however you can simply copy the application bundle out of the archive and it will run with no problems.

1. Right click on the archive in the organiser and choose `Show in Finder`.
2. Right click on the Pomodoro xcarchive package in the Finder window and choose `Show Package Contents`
3. Navigate to `Products` → `Applications`
4. Copy the Pomodoro app bundle to wherever you would like it.
5. Launch it!